# Validating XML with a schema that imports another schema errors about the namespace of elements originally described in imported schema being wrong

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an XML file `Baseplate.xml` (see below) which I'm trying to validate against a schema `place.xsd` (see below), which itself imports another schema `instance.xsd` (see below), which itself imports another schema `type.xsd` (see below). But, in `Baseplate.xml`, on elements for which the schema is described in `instance.xsd` or `type.xsd`, I get the following error:

```
The element 'part' in namespace 'hxxp://luna.localhost/Schema/Place/place.xsd'
 has invalid child element 'position' in namespace 'hxxp://luna.localhost/Schema/Place/place.xsd'.
List of possible elements expected:
 'position' in namespace 'hxxp://luna.localhost/Schema/Place/instance.xsd'.
```

As suggested by Google Gemini, I can work around this by manually specifying the namespace of every element that isn't described in the root schema `place.xsd`:

> `Baseplate.xml` with Gemini's workaround:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<place
    xmlns="hxxp://luna.localhost/Schema/Place/place.xsd"
>
    <tree>
        <part name="Baseplate">
            <position xmlns="hxxp://luna.localhost/Schema/Place/instance.xsd">
                <x xmlns="hxxp://luna.localhost/Schema/Place/type.xsd">0</x>
                <y xmlns="hxxp://luna.localhost/Schema/Place/type.xsd">-0.5</y>
                <z xmlns="hxxp://luna.localhost/Schema/Place/type.xsd">0</z>
            </position>
            <rotation xmlns="hxxp://luna.localhost/Schema/Place/instance.xsd">
                <x xmlns="hxxp://luna.localhost/Schema/Place/type.xsd">0</x>
                <y xmlns="hxxp://luna.localhost/Schema/Place/type.xsd">0</y>
                <z xmlns="hxxp://luna.localhost/Schema/Place/type.xsd">0</z>
            </rotation>
            <size xmlns="hxxp://luna.localhost/Schema/Place/instance.xsd">
                <x xmlns="hxxp://luna.localhost/Schema/Place/type.xsd">100</x>
                <y xmlns="hxxp://luna.localhost/Schema/Place/type.xsd">1</y>
                <z xmlns="hxxp://luna.localhost/Schema/Place/type.xsd">100</z>
            </size>
        </part>
    </tree>
</place>
```

But, that solution isn't very optimal, for obvious reasons...

What am I doing wrong? Am I doing the importing-schemas-in-schemas thing completely wrong? Should I be importing them some other way?

All the search results I can find say to just add `elementFormDefault="qualified"` to the schema, which *did* work when I was getting this error *on elements described in `place.xsd`* (i.e. on `<tree />`), but didn't work to fix the error on elements described in the imported schemas `instance.xsd` and `type.xsd`.

Here are my original files, without the workaround in `Baseplate.xml` suggested by Gemini, which error when trying to validate:

> `Baseplate.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<place
    xmlns="hxxp://luna.localhost/Schema/Place/place.xsd"
>
    <tree>
        <part name="Baseplate">
            <position>
                <x>0</x>
                <y>-0.5</y>
                <z>0</z>
            </position>
            <rotation>
                <x>0</x>
                <y>0</y>
                <z>0</z>
            </rotation>
            <size>
                <x>100</x>
                <y>1</y>
                <z>100</z>
            </size>
        </part>
    </tree>
</place>
```

> `type.xsd`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema 
    targetNamespace="hxxp://luna.localhost/Schema/Place/type.xsd" 
    xmlns:xs="hxxp://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
>
    <xs:complexType name="vector3">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="x" type="xs:decimal" />
            <xs:element name="y" type="xs:decimal" />
            <xs:element name="z" type="xs:decimal" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

> `instance.xsd`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema
    targetNamespace="hxxp://luna.localhost/Schema/Place/instance.xsd" 
    xmlns:xs="hxxp://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:type="hxxp://luna.localhost/Schema/Place/type.xsd"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
>
    <xs:import namespace="hxxp://luna.localhost/Schema/Place/type.xsd" schemaLocation="type.xsd" />

    <xs:complexType name="part">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="position" type="type:vector3" />
            <xs:element name="rotation" type="type:vector3" />
            <xs:element name="size" type="type:vector3" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

> `place.xsd`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema 
    targetNamespace="hxxp://luna.localhost/Schema/Place/place.xsd"
    xmlns:xs="hxxp://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:type="hxxp://luna.localhost/Schema/Place/type.xsd"
    xmlns:instance="hxxp://luna.localhost/Schema/Place/instance.xsd"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
>
    <xs:import namespace="hxxp://luna.localhost/Schema/Place/type.xsd" schemaLocation="type.xsd" />
    <xs:import namespace="hxxp://luna.localhost/Schema/Place/instance.xsd" schemaLocation="instance.xsd" />

    <xs:element name="place">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="tree">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="part" type="instance:part" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your schema describes elements in three different namespaces. If you want to create an XML instance that's valid against that schema, every element has to be in the correct namespace, inconvenient though that may be. The alternative, if you have authority to do so, is to change the schema to use fewer namespaces - which probably means changing the `targetNamespace` attributes, and using `xsl:include` rather than `xsl:import`.

The `elementFormDefault="qualified"` attribute affects the namespace of elements that have a local rather than a global declaration: that is, an element like `tree` that is defined within a complex type definition, rather than being defined globally as a child of `xs:schema`. The setting `qualified` means that the element must be in the target namespace of the schema; in the absence of this attribute, the element must be in no namespace.

Comment: If error messages are cryptic, it's probably because you are writing code in a language that you don't fully understand, and whose terminology you haven't fully mastered. At that point I usually decide that I should stop copying-and-pasting code, and read a good book about the technology in question.